# Get the rate of change by finding the change in price

Tags: r, dataframe, finance, rate

UPDATE:
I'm getting a strange result in the outcome. Occasionally, the earliest date of the result show after 2 or 3 etc times for example

| Item | Kg | Date_1 | Price_1 | change_1 | Date_2 | Price_2 | change_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 1 | 2022-02-01 | 1 | NA | 2022-02-16 | 2 | 1 |
| Meat | NA | NA | NA | NA | 2022-02-03 | 1 | NA |

As you can see, meat is showing no change at first, but the result is showing in the second one. This occurs throughout the program. Any idea why?

I am fairly new to programming. I am working on my portfolio, and am looking at a dataset regarding the price of food from distribution centers to a grocery store. What I am looking at is a set of data with the price, item, and date of transaction. What I am looking for is to find the rate of change from the distribution center to the store, and when it happened.

Note: the price of the item changes from the distribution center.

Here is an example of what I am looking at:

| Date | Item | Price | Kg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2022 | Apple | $1.00 | 1 |
| 02.02.2022 | Meat | $4.00 | 1 |
| 03.02.2022 | Fish | $3.00 | 1 |
| 03.02.2022 | Bread | $1.00 | 1 |
| 15.02.2022 | Meat | $5.00 | 1 |
| 15.02.2022 | Meat | $3.00 | 1 |
| 16.02.2022 | Apple | $2.00 | 1 |
| 20.02.2022 | Fish | $3.00 | 1 |
| 25.02.2022 | Apple | $0.50 | 1 |

As you can see, the price for the same quantity for the same product changes randomly over time. What I would like to analyse is:

1. The rate of change per item
2. When the change occured

This is the ideal outcome:

| item | kg | 1st_price | 1st_price_date | 2nd_price | 2nd_price_date | amount_of_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | $1.00 | 01.02.2022 | $2.00 | 16.02.2022 | +$1.00 |
| Meat | 1 | $4.00 | 02.02.2022 | $5.00 | 15.02.2022 | +$1.00 |
| Bread | 1 | $1.00 | 03.02.2022 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| Fish | 1 | $3.00 | 03.02.2022 | $3.00 | 20.02.2022 | +$0.00 |

#Continuing the table below. These columns would go to the right of the columns above.
#Unfortunetly, StackOverflow was not able to create a table with everything together.
#total_change is for the entire period

| item | 3rd_price | 3rd_price_date | amount_of_change | change_duration_period | total_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | $0.50 | 25.02.2022 | -$1.50 | 01.02.2022-25.02.2022 | -$0.50 |
| Meat | $3.00 | 15.02.2022 | -$2.00 | 02.02.2022-1502.2022 | -$1.00 |
| Bread | N/A | N/A | N/A | 03.02.2022-03.02-2022 | +$0.00 |
| Fish | $3.00 | 20.02.2022 | +$0.00 | 03.02.2022-20.02.2022 | +$0.00 |

As you can see, some items can have more price changes per month than others depending on the item. Some items have drastic changes, some have no changes at all.

Presuming there are over 14,000 unique items what would you recommend to gather the data an place them in a table as seen in the "Ideal outcome" section?

I am still new to programming, please don't be too harsh!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try group_by() from dplyr library? Something like group_by(item) so that you can have each row for each item.

Comment: That helps, however, I am still not sure how to add new columns and widen out the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  # convert Date to a date, and Price to a number
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
         Price = parse_number(Price)) %>%

  # for each Item, arrange by Date, tally, and calc price change
  group_by(Item) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(appearance = row_number(),
         change = Price - lag(Price)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # use the tally to reshape wider the date, price and change
  pivot_wider(names_from = appearance, 
              values_from = c(Date, Price, change),
              names_vary = "slowest")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 11
  Item     Kg Date_1     Price_1 change_1 Date_2     Price_2 change_2 Date_3     Price_3 change_3
  <chr> <int> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Apple     1 2022-02-01       1       NA 2022-02-16       2        1 2022-02-25     0.5     -1.5
2 Meat      1 2022-02-02       4       NA 2022-02-15       5        1 2022-02-15     3       -2  
3 Fish      1 2022-02-03       3       NA 2022-02-20       3        0 NA            NA        0  
4 Bread     1 2022-02-03       1       NA NA              NA        0 NA            NA        0
```

Source data

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Date = c("01.02.2022","02.02.2022",
                       "03.02.2022","03.02.2022","15.02.2022","15.02.2022",
                       "16.02.2022","20.02.2022","25.02.2022"),
              Item = c("Apple","Meat","Fish",
                       "Bread","Meat","Meat","Apple","Fish","Apple"),
             Price = c("$1.00","$4.00","$3.00",
                       "$1.00","$5.00","$3.00","$2.00","$3.00","$0.50"),
                Kg = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!!!! 
I take it that the parse_number() finds the different numbers in the df?

Comment: Your pasted data shows prices like "$1.00," and `readr::parse_number` converts it from a text string with the `$` to a number (1.0) we can calculate on.

Comment: I'm getting a strange result in the outcome. Occasionally, the earliest date of the result show after 2 or 3 etc times for example

Item     Kg     Date_1         Price_1      change_1       Date_2      Price_2      change_2
Apples  1     2022-02-01       1            NA              2022-02-16      2                 1
Meat    NA       NA              NA            NA             2022-02-03       1                NA

As you can see, meat is showing no change at first, but the result is showing in the second one. This occurs throughout the program. Any idea why?

Comment: It sounds like you have NA values in your original data or introduced in one of the cleaning steps, e.g. perhaps dates formatted a different way. I'd suggest examining the output along the way to see where that happened, for instance add `%>% View` after the `parse_number` step.